# Purview of video is not showing in MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using this code for putting video on the MPMoviePlayerController but I am not  seeing the purview of video on the MPMoviePlayerController,it is displaying only black screen.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePath];
  if (playerViewController != nil){
      [playerViewController release];
   }
   playerViewController =[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init]retain];
   playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height);
   playerViewController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   playerViewController setContentURL:url];
   playerViewController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
   playerViewController.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;
   playerViewController.repeatMode=NO;
   [videoView addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

Comment: What is movie path?means it is string or any thing else?

Comment: @Vishal thanx for reply it is string type

Answer (score 0):

Try like that and then check it working or not:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
```

Comment: Give me full line of movie path string.